# Can't resolve issue related to $http.get in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the code i have inject all the necessary dependencies in angular controller.I have shown only main part on which i am confuse.

```
$scope.ipList=["http://www.google.com",
                    "http://www.yahoo.com",
                    "http://hello",
                    "http://www.facebook.com",
                    "http://hi",
                    "http://bye"
                  ];
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.ipList.length;i++)
            {   
                console.log(i); //1st console
                $http.get($scope.ipList[i])
                .then(function(response) {
                     console.log(i);
                 });
            }

 when i am executing this then 1st console is printing right result i.e.
0,1,2,3,4,5 but the 2nd console is printing only 5.
I want to execute $http.get() part every time with loop.So what should i do.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.then(function(response) {
                     console.log(i);
                 });
```

This is async function, by the time it fires, `i` has already incremented.  When the function eventually fires, it logs the current version of `i`, not what it would be if it that function were to fire immediately.

You can do a couple of different things to get around the array copying.  wrapping the http.get in a function and firing it will copy the variable values.  For example:

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.ipList.length;i++)
        {   
            console.log(i); //1st console
            (
               function (i) {
                   $http.get($scope.ipList[i])
                   .then(function(response) {console.log(i);})
            )(i);

  //depending on the scenario, I would probably extract this outside of the 
  //loop so it doesn't create it each time the function fires.
  //this really depends on the code inside it though, and what needs
  //to operate through closure etc. 

        }
```

Here is an example using the setTimout function, which will force firing asynchronously too.  https://jsfiddle.net/q0nmph0j/

Copying a variable to another variable will force the second variable to not update once the first has too.

```
var first = 0
var second = first; 

first = 3;

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

Output:

```
3
0
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qf776j3e/

Comment: Thanks Kevin for being so quick.What i want it will clear by reading the code so what should i do?